# Controlled interface Implementation

Tags: java, interface

In Serialization, the class which we want to be serialized has to implement the Serializable interface, otherwise a NotSerializableException is thrown. There are many other examples like that in the various features of Java. Now I just want to know how to bring in such control in custom classes and interfaces. I have an interface called Agent. There can be many different types of Agents, all of them must implement the Agent interface. I also have a class called Node. Nodes create Agents. Now how to bring in control in such a situation, such that an agent always much implement Agent interface, otherwise an exception will be thrown. I might sound a bit vague, but if someone can provide me with the general idea, then I can provide further details if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a Node method which must take an Agent, you specify that the argument has to be an Agent.

```
interface Node {
    void method(Agent agent); // must be an Agent.
    Agent returnAgent(); // must return an Agent.
}
```

Serialization is a special case.  This is because not all types which are serializable are Serializable.  Built in types like int[] is serializable but doesn't implement Serializable. This type of check cannot be done by the compiler and can only be done at runtime.

Comment: and where to throw an exception?

Comment: You don't need to throw an exception as the compiler will prevent an invalid type being using.

Comment: I like your solution a lot better than mine. Much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if the Agent implements the interface before your Node creates the Agent.

```
public class CheckForInterface
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Class cl = (Class)Class.forName("TestImpl");
        Class[] itfs = cl.getInterfaces();

        for(Class c : itfs)
        {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}

import java.io.Serializable;

public class TestImpl implements Serializable
{
    public TestImpl()
    {

    }
}
```

This outputs: interface java.io.Serializable